# Exporting companion object methods in ScalaJS?

Tags: scala, scala.js

When using ScalaJS, I can export an object and all members like so

```
@JSExport object Thing {
    @JSExport def doThing(x:Int) = x * 2
}
```

However when creating a companion object, ScalaJS no longer appears to export the methods.

```
@JSExport @JSExportAll case class Thing(x:Int)

@JSExport object Thing {
   @JSExport def fromNumber(x:Int) = Thing(x)
}
```

In this example I now have Javascript class I can instantiate by calling `Thing(n)`, but there doesn't appear to be any method `Thing.fromNumber` available.

Is this possible with ScalaJS?

(Note: Currently using "ScalaJS 0.6.8" with "Scala 2.11.8" and "SBT 0.13.9)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to give the companion object another name when you export it:

```
@JSExport @JSExportAll case class Thing(x:Int)

@JSExport("ThingOps")
object Thing {
   @JSExport def fromNumber(x:Int) = Thing(x)
}
```

Now call `ThingOps().fromNumber(1)`.

What you are asking for are static methods. Scala.js currently doesn't support these (see [#1902](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1902)).

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
Thing().fromNumber(...)
```

(Notice the extra parenthesis behind 'Thing')

Comment: Unfortunately 'Thing()' refers to the case class constructor.